# Fetch xml value in the string

Tags: java, xml, string, soap

Need some help to parse xml value from a string, I have got xml as a string.

I have a string as

```
<ns3:sometag><ns4:somechildtag>foo</ns4:somechildtag></ns3:sometag>
```

Now I want to get the value of somechildtag using string parsing or regex map in java?

Comment: Neither - use a SAX or DOM parser for XML.

Comment: its a string which can't be parsed as there are new line and escape characters included

Comment: New line is no problem.  Those are valid XML.   Escape characters?  Please explain.  They should be valid XML.  If yes, you can and should use a parser.  If not, they aren't XML.

Comment: @duffymo Or StAX or JAXB or XPath.

Comment: Thanks, I will give it a shot with JAXB

Comment: If you can't handle a parser you won' get far with JAXB. You realize that everything suggested above depends on a parser?  Do the simplest thing: parse to DOM and get your value.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in one of the comments too, you would need some parser to work with your XML - There could be [DOM](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java_xml/java_dom_parser.htm) based parser or [SAX](https://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-read-xml-file-in-java-sax-parser/) based parser or [stream](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jaxp/stax/why.html) based parser. Each one of them have different pro/cons -

If your XML is simple/short then you might want to load it in memory and play around - A clear and concise example can be found at [here](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java_xml/java_dom_parse_document.htm)

Also, before you play with JAXB or anything else which would require a schema beforehand, I would suggest understand the concepts first, above.